# QLPreviewController display out of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

Bug screenshot link:

[image]

I use QLPreviewController, but it display out of screen.I don't know why? Need Help, thx!

```
self.previewingFileInfo = fileInfo;

QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
previewController.dataSource = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController 
*)controller {
    return self.previewingFileInfo ? 1 : 0;
}

- (id<QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller 
previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return self.previewingFileInfo.URL;
}

//self.previewingFileInfo.URL --->>> file:///Users/liman/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C472DBF9-7DB5-4A09-B443-16F1D40EED52/data/Containers/Data/Application/E7E03D12-FD59-47F6-B2A8-20D75D6B5252/Library/Caches/Logs.zip
```

Comment: If you think your implementation is correct, but suspect an issue with QuickLook itself, you should definitely file a radar at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: agree with the above, i have the same bug as well. my implementation worked fine until ios11